# How can I store multiple instances of different data with the same keyword in Firebase using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an iOS app that has a shopping cart system. I have a screen for choosing an item and then once the item is clicked on, it goes to a new screen for selecting the quantity. When the item is added to the cart, I would like to store it in Firebase so that when the user goes to their cart, the data can be loaded from Firebase. I tried the following:

```
@IBAction func addToCartButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let reference = Database.database().reference.child("UserCart").child(Auth.auth().currentUser.uid)
    reference.updateChildValues(["Item Name": itemName, "Item Price": itemPrice, "Item Quantity": itemQuantity])
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I do this, I do not achieve what I want because if the user adds another item from the Order View Controller, then the existing information that I just wrote to Firebase gets overwritten. I understand that this is how it is designed to work so I was wondering if there was another way that I could write to Firebase and have multiple instances of `itemName`, `itemPrice`, and `itemQuantity` all in Firebase. I later plan to read this data and store it in an array. If it helps, I am using Swift 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to read the documentation on [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data).

For writing a new item, the thing to do would be to [append to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) using [`childByAutoId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)childByAutoId):

```
let reference = Database.database().reference
    .child("UserCart")
    .child(Auth.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .childByAutoId()
```

The SDK will generate a unique ID an use that as the path of the written child.  Since each call to `childByAutoId()` generates a unique ID, each new child will be added separately and will not overwrite anything.

Comment: Could you please also edit your answer to cover how I can get put these into an array. I should have made this clear the first time but I edited my question to cover what else I need.

Comment: Please ask psot followup question separately.  It's expected that the question show an attempt at solving the problem.  Stack Overflow is limited to one question/issue per post in order to make it easy for people to search and navigate.